# Apache Shiro Implicit [url] restriction

Tags: apache, security, permissions, shiro

I'm using [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) to manage my applications security with great success. However, I'm trying to specify a **url** path in my *shiro.ini* file that will prevent access to a specified page based on the subjects allocated '*permissions*'.

I know the permissions are generally working as I can use the `SecurityUtil` to restrict access to methods and functions and this works fine.

```
SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted("account:create");
```

I am obviously missing something because when I try to apply this through my ini configuration file using the default ***perms*** filter the permission seem to be ignored.

Relevant parts of my shiro.ini file:

```
[urls]
...
/accounts/create.jsf = perms["account:create"]
...
```

(obtained from [Shiro Docs](http://shiro.apache.org/web.html))

I would have thought that when the specified **url** is accessed the ***perms*** filter is instantiated, the subject is found to be lacking the implied permission and the page is not rendered! However the page seems to be rendered just fine. :(

Do I need to create my own implementation of the ***perms*** filter and specify its action? I would have thought that was the point of supplying a default!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely forgot that the order of the filters in the ini file causes a 'short circuit' when a match is found.

Above this filter I had a ***role*** based filter that was matched, ergo the perms filter was never reached.

```
[urls]
...
/** = auth, roles[XXX]
...
/accounts/create.jsf = perms["account:create"]
```